# icon fonst are showing weard symbols somtimes

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, font-awesome

I am using both font awesome and line icons in my React project, it is happening for both especially when my developer tool is open, I am seeing these strange symbols but once I refresh icons are showing properly.

[image]

checked the network log things seem to be okay, happening for the past few days.